# GCP static website hosting via bucket does not serve configured error and index pages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, google-bucket

I'm trying to serve a simple static React SPA through GCP bucket as described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

It is crucial for my structure that for `/my_directory`, the file `/my_directory/index.html` is served.

I think what I want is exactly described here in the ["Three-object bucket" in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#three-object_bucket)

This is my config:

[image]

This is my file structure:

[image]

In the folder test_2023_11_03_c there is a file "index.html"

But it doesn't work.

For

- https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket-name, I expect to get the main `index.html` served. However, instead I get a list of all files in the bucket.
- https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket-name/something-that-doesnt_exist, I expect the content of my_error.html to be served. However, instead I get `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: my-bucket-name/something-that-doesnt_exist</Details></Error>`
- https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket-name/test_2023_11_03_c, I expect the content of the directory's index.html to be served. However, instead I get the same error: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: my-bucket-name/test_2023_11_03_c</Details></Error>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access files without a custom domain. Hence, You are experiencing this behavior. It is stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-api) that:

> The `MainPageSuffix` and `NotFoundPage` website configurations are only used for requests that come to Cloud Storage through a CNAME or A redirect. For example, a request to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) shows the index page, but an equivalent request to [storage.googleapis.com/www.example.com](http://storage.googleapis.com/www.example.com) does not.
>
> Thus, `API` behavior for requests to `Cloud Storage` domains, such as [storage.googleapis.com/www.example.com](http://storage.googleapis.com/www.example.com), is preserved. For example, you can continue to list objects in the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) bucket as you would for any other bucket. In the case of the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) bucket, the object listing you receive includes `404.html` and `index.html`

Also check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) to set a website configuration for a bucket.